# Como fazer repetição de div com json com conteúdo dinâmico?

Tags: javascript, html5, json, loop

No momento quero fazer com que uma div tenha um conteúdo de um JSON. No caso, a primeira div tem o conteúdo "0" do JSON, e que se repita em loop, até chegar na quantidade máxima de itens dentro do JSON.

```
[...]
<section>
<div>
<p id="nome">Texto</p>
</div>               
</section>
[...]
```

JSON

```
var jsonnomes = {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 3,
    "nomes": [{
        "name": "Pedro",
        "idade": "33"
    }, {
        "name": "Bruno",
        "idade": "27"
    }, {
        "name": "Julia",
        "idade": "25"
    }]
}
```

Código que estou usando no momento para chamar o JSON é esse:

```
function main() {
    let data = jsonnomes
    let newsJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(newsJSON.articles);
    const keys = Object.keys(newsJSON.nomes);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        var Autor = document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML += newsJSON.articles[key]["name"] + "<br>";
    })
```

Não sei se tenho que criar outra função para o loop ou se posso colocar junto dessa função "main". Também não sei como fazer esse código. Quem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Só lembrando que o objetivo é repetir a div com seu style, mudando apenas o conteúdo dentro da mesma. Conteúdo este que está em um JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<section>
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const arr = [];
const jsonnomes = {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 3,
    "nomes": [{
        "name": "Pedro",
        "idade": "33"
    }, {
        "name": "Bruno",
        "idade": "27"
    }, {
        "name": "Julia",
        "idade": "25"
    }]
}

const renderInfos = () => {
const { nomes } = jsonnomes;
    const res = nomes.forEach((item) => {
    arr.push(`
      <div>
        <p>Nome: ${item.name} - Idade: ${item.idade}</p>
      </div>    
    `)
  })
section.innerHTML = arr.join(' ');  
}

renderInfos()
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ax9hgLkf/

Answer (score 0):

teste o seguinte codigo

```
    var jsonnomes = {
      "status": "ok",
      "totalResults": 3,
      "nomes": [{
        "name": "Pedro",
        "idade": "33"
      }, {
        "name": "Bruno",
        "idade": "27"
      }, {
        "name": "Julia",
        "idade": "25"
      }]
    }
    
    var wData = jsonnomes.nomes;
    var wHtml = ""
    for (let wIdx = 0; wIdx < wData.length; wIdx++) {
      const wElement = wData[wIdx];
      wHtml += "Nome : " + wElement["name"] + "  Idade :" + wElement["idade"] + "<br>"

}
document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML += wHtml
```

Comment: Ele funciona do mesmo jeito que o meu codigo, puxa o json e joga tudo na mesma div, acho que tenho que mudar o id da <div> e do <p>. Era para ser em <div> separadas, um nome em cada junto com sua respectava idade.